# Neo4j cypher with parameters returns success but doesn't create anything?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I send this:

```
{
  "query" :  "MATCH (p) WHERE p.id={id} CREATE (c {props}) CREATE UNIQUE p-[r:CHILD]->c",
  "params" : {  
      "id" : ["{0000-0000-0000-0000}","{0000-0000-0000-0000}","{0000-0000-0000-0004}"],
      "props" : [ {
          "id" : "{0000-0000-0000-0004}",
          "type": 48,
          "title" : "TestNode" 
       },{
          "id" : "{0000-0000-0000-0005}",
          "type": 49,
          "title" : "TestNode"
       },{
          "id" : "{0000-0000-0000-0006}",
          "type": 49,
          "title" : "TestNode"
       }]
   }
}
```

Via the restful cypher api, I get back "success" but nothing was created. If I send through this:

```
{
  "query" :  "MATCH (p) WHERE p.id={id} CREATE (c {props}) CREATE UNIQUE p-[r:CHILD]->c",
  "params" : {  
    "id" : "{0000-0000-0000-0000}",
    "props" : [ {
        "id" : "{0000-0000-0000-0001}",
        "type": 48,
        "title" : "TestNode"
    },{
        "id" : "{0000-0000-0000-0002}",
        "type": 49,
        "title" : "TestNode"
    } ]
  }
}
```

It creates two children of 0000-0000-0000-0000 as expected. So something about the way I'm specifying two arrays isn't working.

I was hoping to be able to create large tree structures by essentially specifying parent ID/child to create parameters. The other option is that I use the latter style cypher and the transactional endpoint... but I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong in the first one. Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to do:

```
MATCH (p) WHERE p.id IN {id}
CREATE (c {props}) 
CREATE UNIQUE (p)-[r:CHILD]->(c)
```

The = operator is an exact comparison.

Comment: Right, but you have an array there. Give it one id if you want an exact comparison. The way you have it, it's trying to find a p where p has an id of that array value.

Comment: `IN` will do an exact comparison for each value of the array, `=` for the whole array

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for the clarification, I see why it doesn't work. I was hoping it would walk the two arrays side by side so that the first entry in the {id} is substituted in along with the first entry in {props}, then the second entry from both arrays. Using IN would match any of them rather than the specific parent that I need, so I guess it's just not the right way to do it.

Comment: just break it into 3 statements.

Comment: Yep, just playing around with how best to create tree's with ten's of thousands of nodes.

The parameter documentation could also be a little clearer - I thought that if you provided an array in the parameters section it would actually be running that query once for each entry in the array, rather than just substituting the array in directly.